# NPM: difficulty in installing new modules

Tags: node.js, module, npm, npm-install

I am facing problems installing any new modules in nmp. `npm install modulename`. But when i use `-g` flag, it installs, but My script still does not recognize it.  What is the problem and a possible solution?

The debug log is shown below.

```
devanshd:~/workspace $ cat /home/ubuntu/workspace/npm-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'mocha' ]
2 info using npm@4.0.2
3 info using node@v4.1.2
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData mocha
8 silly fetchNamedPackageData mocha
9 silly mapToRegistry name mocha
10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
11 silly mapToRegistry registry http://localhost:15443/
12 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
12 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'mocha',
12 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,
12 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: 'mocha',
12 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'mocha',
12 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
12 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
12 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
13 silly mapToRegistry uri http://localhost:15443/mocha
14 verbose request uri http://localhost:15443/mocha
15 verbose request no auth needed
16 info attempt registry request try #1 at 9:55:48 AM
17 verbose request id bb344d5f4ea94faf
18 http request GET http://localhost:15443/mocha
19 http 404 http://localhost:15443/mocha
20 verbose headers { 'content-type': 'application/json',
20 verbose headers   date: 'Sat, 19 Nov 2016 09:55:48 GMT',
20 verbose headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
20 verbose headers   'content-length': '19' }
21 silly get cb [ 404,
21 silly get   { 'content-type': 'application/json',
21 silly get     date: 'Sat, 19 Nov 2016 09:55:48 GMT',
21 silly get     connection: 'keep-alive',
21 silly get     'content-length': '19' } ]
22 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: missing : mocha
22 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at makeError (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:302:12)
22 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at CachingRegistryClient.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:290:14)
22 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request._callback (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:210:14)
22 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.self.callback (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
22 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
22 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.emit (events.js:172:7)
22 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1081:10)
22 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
22 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
22 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1001:12)
22 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for mocha { [Error: missing : mocha] pkgid: 'mocha', statusCode: 404, code: 'E404' }
23 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
24 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
25 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
26 silly install printInstalled
27 verbose stack Error: missing : mocha
27 verbose stack     at makeError (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:302:12)
27 verbose stack     at CachingRegistryClient.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:290:14)
27 verbose stack     at Request._callback (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:210:14)
27 verbose stack     at Request.self.callback (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
27 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
27 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:172:7)
27 verbose stack     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1081:10)
27 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
27 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
27 verbose stack     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1001:12)
28 verbose statusCode 404
29 verbose pkgid mocha
30 verbose cwd /home/ubuntu/workspace
31 error Linux 4.2.0-c9
32 error argv "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/bin/npm" "install" "mocha"
33 error node v4.1.2
34 error npm  v4.0.2
35 error code E404
36 error 404 missing : mocha
37 error 404
38 error 404 'mocha' is not in the npm registry.
39 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
40 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
41 error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
42 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Looks like you're having Internet connection problems, or `npm` was having registry problems. Try it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something messed up Your default url to npm. It points at `http://localhost:15443/`

Use `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` to fix it